# Booting Windows on centOS

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, centos, bootable-media

Obviously just plugging a bootable Windows 10 USB drive on it doesn't cause centOS to open that drive and show me the Windows 10 install GUI like it would on another OS. However, I'm done with centOS and need to reinstall Windows 10 on that machine, how would I go about doing this?

I'm not able to get to BIOS (I've tried many times), and honestly, I'm not familiar with the grub> terminal and I don't know how to select the Windows USB as what the system needs to boot from (the USB is being detected as HD0 (msdos1).

Apologies if ^ was extremely confusing or nonsensical, I'll gladly clarify something if need-be:) I just need to install Windows 10 on this computer and get rid of centOS (8 I believe).

Comment: If the USB stick has been created by Microsoft MediaCreationTool it should be bootable. Reboot your PC and on next reboot select to boot from the USB stick.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Robert has said.. there is a "magic key/combo" that will either bring up the boot menu or allow you into the bios to enable this menu or let you pick the boot order.  This is dependent on what kind of machine/motherboard you have.  Please tell us more information on what you have..

Comment: It's an old Dell tower PC, I've tried multiple key combinations to try to get the BIOS open but it's unfortunately not working. @Robert thank you for your reply as well, the option to boot does no exist when I start the centOS machine, this is what I'm trying to fix.